# How to fix "cannot retrieve repository metadata" when installing CentOS 6.5 from Kickstart over FTP?

Tags: centos, ftp, kvm, kickstart

I am pulling my hair out trying to fix this. I am attempting to install CentOS 6.5 over an FTP server on KVM from the physical host. I have vsftpd installed, selinux set to permissive, and iptables temporarily flushed. My installation is copied to `/var/ftp/pub/inst/CentOS_6.5_Final/`. My kickstart config is `/var/ftp/pub/inst/ks.cfg`. 
I `chmod -R 777` for both the file and directory (without the `-R` for `ks.cfg`).

The first command I append to the installation menu is `ks=x.x.x.x/pub/inst/ks.cfg`
The VM is able to retrieve my ks.cfg easily once I flushed my iptables. It starts reformatting my virtual drives with no problems. As soon as it gets to retrieving the repository it spits out `cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository.`

When I Ctl+Alt+F3 inside the VM, the following output is displayed:
`Failed to get <the path to my IP>/CentOS_6.5_Final/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errorno 14] PYCURL ERROR 7 - "couldn't connect to host"`

Here is my kick start config:

```
# Kickstart file automatically generated by anaconda.
#version=DEVEL
install
url --url ftp://x.x.x.x/pub/inst/CentOS_6.5_Final/
lang en_US.UTF-8
keyboard us
network --onboot no --device eth0 --bootproto static --ip x.x.x.x --netmask x.x.x.x --gateway x.x.x.x --nameserver 8.8.8.8 --hostname <myhostname> --noipv6

rootpw  --iscrypted <very long string of hash>
firewall --service=ssh
authconfig --enableshadow --passalgo=sha512
selinux --enforcing
timezone --utc America/Denver
bootloader --location=mbr --driveorder=vda
# The following is the partition information you requested
# Note that any partitions you deleted are not expressed
# here so unless you clear all partitions first, this is
# not guaranteed to work
zerombr
clearpart --drives=vda --all
ignoredisk --only-use=vda

#part None --fstype=efi --onpart=sda1 --noformat
#part None --fstype=ext4 --onpart=sda2 --noformat
#part swap --onpart=sda3 --noformat

part / --fstype=ext4 --size=8000
part /boot --fstype=ext4 --size=500
part /home --fstype=ext4 --size=1000
part swap --size=1000


#repo --name="CentOS" --baseurl=http://x.x.x.x/inst/ --cost=100

%packages
@base
@core
@debugging
@basic-desktop
@desktop-debugging
@desktop-platform
@directory-client
@fonts
@general-desktop
@graphical-admin-tools
@input-methods
@internet-applications
@internet-browser
@java-platform
@legacy-x
@network-file-system-client
@office-suite
@print-client
@remote-desktop-clients
@server-platform
@server-policy
@workstation-policy
@x11
mtools
pax
oddjob
wodim
sgpio
enisoimage
device-mapper-persistent-data
abrt-gui
samba-winbind
certmonger
pam_krb5
krb5-workstation
libXmu
%end
shutdown
firstboot --disabled`
```

*edit*

Okay... I just figured out it was a networking issue when setting up the static properties. I changed `--bootproto static` to `--bootproto dhcp` and removed everything afterwards except `--noipv6`. Apparently I need to learn more about our new router-modem combo from comcast. I really hate that modem.

Comment: When I was debugging installation-by-ftp, it was useful to enable logging on the ftp server. With vsftpd, this is done with the xferlog_enable and log_ftp_protocol configuration options.

Comment: That is great advice, thanks! Fortunately I found the solution to an apparent trivial error, but by asking I have gained a solid piece of information from you.